# mongodb: why rust mongodb driver does not support bulk write operation? are any workarounds?

Tags: mongodb, rust

I found discussion about the topic here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUST-271
The latest answer:

> Hello! We don't implement the bulk write API and have no plans to add
> it. From dealing with it in other drivers, we've found that the
> semantics tend to be non-obvious, especially with regards to error
> handling, and it doesn't provide a whole lot of technical benefit
> given that it still sends different write types in separate commands
> to the server (i.e. the same way as if each of insert_many,
> update_many, delete_many, etc. were called separately).

But there is something still not clear for me.
Why that answer mention `*_many` (`update_many`, `insert_many` etc) type operations if bulk write is set of `*_one` (`update_one`, `insert_one` etc)?
Ok, `insert_many` uses bulk write under the hood. But bulk write and update many are different. Because first one uses a set of `update_one` operations which have different filters and update bodies for each one. And `update_many` has one filter for many updates.
So, `update_many` cannot replace bulk write. Am I right? If so, then why MongoDB rust driver does not support bulk write? If I am not right can you please explain why? Maybe I do not understand some details.
It seems if I use `update_one` a lot of time I get bad performance compared to bulk write. Because in case of bulk write I will connect once to MongoDB compared to update_one where I need one connection per `update_one`.